# Raster values shows no data when using identify features tool

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, nodata, identify

I used vector to raster function in QGIS, to convert some points with different values to raster. I tried to use the "Identify Features" to check values for each raster box. The values shows no data like shown below:

[image]

The vector points I converted from have normal values.

Why cant I see the values? and what can I do to see the values?

Comment: The pixel you clicked on just has no data. How many (approx.) pixels do not have data? There must have gone something wrong during the raster creation if you are convinced there should be other data. Can you provide a detailed description of your points (values and where they are located) and the settings you chose to create the raster?

Comment: Also, if you are working with multiple data at once you might find it more useful to use the identify tool in 'table' mode rather than 'tree' mode. It is easier to see (in my opinion) which files have data at a certain point and which do not, which could help you track down where the lack of data is coming from as mentioned above.